# How does PeopleSoft App Engine program flow occur

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode, peoplesoft-app-engine

I am learning more about PeopleSoft Application Engine program flow. From what I've read in PeopleBooks, any actions within a step that specify a `Do Select` , `Do When` or `Do While` perform a looping activity, where all subsequent Actions (within that step) are looped through one row at a time.

I have seen some App Engine programs, including the below one where a `Do Select` action occurs in a step, followed by a `Call Section` action that executes anoter section of the program. Does this mean that the loops still iterates over the called section one row at a time, just like any other action(s) would be repeated within the calling step?

My 2nd question is specific to the below App Engine program. In the highlighted PeopleCode action at the bottom of the program, you can see it runs PeopleCode to check/compare data elements and then Exit. My question is whether this code is running within the context of the looping action occuring above where it is executing one row at a time, or is this executing by looking at everything in the buffer at the same time? I would think it can only process row-by-row as it needs to correctly exit/break from the step. Hopefully my question makes sense, but I'm happy to clarify is needed. Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both of your assumptions are correct.

If you call another program section within a `Do ...`, then that call gets executed once for every row that is returned from the `Do ...`.  Within the context of the called section, the data in your state tables and temp tables will the same as they were when you hit the `Call Section` action.

When you execute a PeopleCode action, it executes with whatever data is in the state records and temp tables at that time.